# Computing 2 variable function given 2 points

Tags: shader, linear-algebra, unreal-engine4

I have 2 points in 3D space of the form `(x1, y1, z1 = 1)` and `(x2, y2, z2 = 0)`. I know that all the x and y are in the `[0, 1]` interval, and I want to compute the function for that interval, knowing the maximum slope for that function happens on the line that crosses the 2 given points.

The function is linear: z = ax + by + c

The objective of this problem is to create an unreal shader that creates a variable width line between 2 points on the screen, if there's another solution that's ok for me too.

I have tried a few linear equation solving processes but I can't seem to get the correct function.

Comment: Why using shader? You can simply use `DrawDebugLine` to visualize this line.

Comment: Because I need the line in postprocess to draw other stuff on it.